# FlexSlider working in IE but not on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, flexslider

I don't know what is going wrong with my FlexSlider but it doesn't work on my Firefox and Chrome. You can have a look at it at www.cabothealth.com.au. However, it doesn't work on demo page at www.woothemes.com/flexslider either.

I am running the latest version of Firefox and Chrome on Windows 8. 
Could anyone please help? Thanks in advance.